# Using Mercurial to start a new project similar to an existing one

Tags: version-control, mercurial

I have a project on a Mercurial (HG) repository. I am about to start a new project that I would like to start by using the exact same code as the mentioned project. The two projects are completely unrelated. Even though they do similar stuff, each one is for a different client, carry different names, different branding, different art.

My question is:

What would be the recommended approach:

1. Cloning (hg clone) the project and start making changes?
2. Archiving (hg archive) the project and making a new repository (hg init) on the archived copy?
3. Any other option I am not considering?

Thanks a lot.

Comment: Ignoring the version control aspects, this kinda sounds like you should spin the core functionality into some kind of library such that you don't have to maintain two (largely identical) code bases unnecessarily.

Comment: Hmm, does mercurial not implements something like svn:external in svn?

Comment: @Wrikken: I haven't used SVN but if external means making another copy of your central repository then that will never be in Mercurial. Mercurial is distributed and everybody has a full repository locally.

Comment: @Gian: Totally agree with you. I might end up creating a base library, but for now, is a pretty small project so I can start just by cloning/copying it.

Comment: @Ashish: svn:external would tell svn that a certain file or folder can be found at another location (possibly pinned by revision). See it has a `clone hg <other location>` in one of the subdirs, but the external reference to it can be saves, so people fetching the 'major' project would do a 'subfetch' for the externals needed (or pass a parameter disabling it if they don't which to grab external code. See: http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.0/ch07s03.html It makes for some handy 'packaging' of a standard library / project into others.

Comment: @Wrikken: Oh, I see. That can be handy. I'm not sure if you can actually do that with hg. I remember from a Google Tech Talk by Linus on git that you have to clone the whole repository with git (and hg and git share pretty much all the same design principles, but I'm not sure). Linus suggested since merging is now easy one should rather have different repositories for each sub-section of the project instead of having a single big one.

Comment: @Ashish: aha, well, with svn:externals it would be in different repos (or another location in the same), with the major upside of having all dependencies automatically imported.

Comment: svn:expernals have an almost exact analog in mercurial SubRepos

Comment: @Wrikken The HG counterpart, I believe, is Mercurial [subrepos](http://mercurial.selenic.com/wiki/subrepos).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If it uses the "exact same code as the mentioned project" and differs only in branding then you would probably want to branch off from the original project. Although initially things are identical client requirements may diverge (read branch) later on. Also the content files would begin to differ.

Short answer: Yes clone and branch off each project. With distributed revision control you can always merge if you need to.

Answer (score 5):

I'm going to expand on the comment I made earlier suggesting that common functionality should be put into a library to avoid duplicated effort in maintaining the same code base in two places and suggest that if you can get away with making each instance a branch of the common codebase, then that's probably ideal.  Hopefully that way if you fix a bug in one branch, it should be easy enough to merge branches or at least apply the changes in consistent ways easily.

Answer (score 1):

Before you take anyone's (correct!) advice to branch, please read this article: http://stevelosh.com/blog/2009/08/a-guide-to-branching-in-mercurial/ and decide which of the many, valid ways to branch in mercurial is right for you.  People hear "branch" and use `hg branch` which is one way to branch, but not the only one or necessarily the right one.

Were I you I'd just clone, start working in the clone, and reconcile them later when you can (per Gian's great advice) refactor into a common base library.